# How do you retrieve an objects name from a list and pass it to a function to retrieve that objects property? 'str' object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x

New to python and OOP. Hopefully I'm using the correct terms. I'm using a list to hold all of my objects. I want to reference this list to get the name of the object that I would like to get a property value for. I then want to pass this name to a function to get one or more properties. But I'm getting a string error (because the list is returning a string of the object name and not the actual object).

Here is the code:

```
class creature():
def __init__(self, name, legs):
    self.name = name
    self.legs = legs

rat = creature("rat",4)
mouse = creature("mouse",4)
beaver = creature("beaver",4)
squirrel = creature("squirrel",4)
chimpanzee = creature("chimpanzee",2)
gorilla = creature("gorilla",2)
orangutan = creature("orangutan",2)
spider_monkey = creature("spider_monkey",2)
black_widow = creature("black_widow",8)
recluse = creature("recluse",8)
wolf_spider = creature("wolf_spider",8)
daddy_long_leg = creature("daddy_long_leg",8)

def checkLegs(critter):
    nbrLegs = critter.legs
    return success

animals = [
        ['rat', 'mouse', 'beaver', 'squirrel'],    
        ['chimpanzee','gorilla','orangutan','spider_monkey'],
        ['black_widow','recluse','wolf_spider','daddy_long_leg']
    ]

numberOfLegs = checkLegs(recluse)
print("The Recluse has: ")
print(numberOfLegs)
print(" legs")
```

Here is the response:

```
The test animal is:  orangutan
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Python37/help.py", line 32, in <module>
numberOfLegs = checkLegs(testAnimal)
 File "Python37/help.py", line 20, in checkLegs
nbrLegs = critter.legs
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'legs'
```

Comment: Your code doesn't give this error, it gives `NameError: name 'success' is not defined`. Replacing `success` with constant `4` gives output without errors. So, you have to modify your post that code and the error match and others can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things here that are preventing this from working. Look at your checkLegs function. It is returning something called success...however, that's not being used anywhere, and since you haven't wrapped it in ""s (I assume you were trying to return the word success to check if the function works) it is trying to return it as a variable, but of course it's undefined. You want the function to return the result of the code you use the function to execute. In this case you want to return nbrLegs. You also need to check the indentation of your constructor. You also don't need the array of animals since you're already defining them in your class. Other than that you were pretty close. Here's your code, with the fixes implemented:

```
class creature():
def __init__(self, name, legs):
    self.name = name
    self.legs = legs

rat = creature("rat",4)
mouse = creature("mouse",4)
beaver = creature("beaver",4)
squirrel = creature("squirrel",4)
chimpanzee = creature("chimpanzee",2)
gorilla = creature("gorilla",2)
orangutan = creature("orangutan",2)
spider_monkey = creature("spider_monkey",2)
black_widow = creature("black_widow",8)
recluse = creature("recluse",8)
wolf_spider = creature("wolf_spider",8)
daddy_long_leg = creature("daddy_long_leg",8)

def checkLegs(critter):
    nbrLegs = critter.legs
    return nbrLegs


numberOfLegs = checkLegs(recluse)
print("The Recluse has: " + str(numberOfLegs) + " legs")
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this. I should have reviewed the code better and entered it in properly. This was my first post. My return should have been return nbrLegs.  I totally wrecked my question.  :( I provided the wrong code. But I may have found a solution (need to test it later). I removed the quotes from each of the animal in the list. testAnimal = animals[1][2]  ... numberOfLegs = checkLegs(testAnimal)

Comment: I think that will work fine, but it's also probably a wash efficiency wise. If you wanted to use the list of animals then you could also write a function that parses the list for an animal you search for, then creates an object for it based on your class.